# PWA splash screen image does not display on Android despite having 192x192 and 512x512 images

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Using Chrome 69 for Android and Windows, I am having problems with the splash screen.  While running on Windows as a standalone app, it appears to have no splash screen concept at all (I wish that were documented), but I am more concerned that my android PWA shows a splash screen without the icons configured in my manifest.  The splash background is correct, and the app name is displayed... just no image.

I have both 192x192 and 512x512 images.  When I run a Lighthouse audit I get 100 on every point, except for the insidious "Content is not sized correctly for the viewport" failure.

Both images show up in Chrome/Dev Console/Application/Manifest/Icons and my 192x192 is used correctly as an app icon for both Windows and Android.

Here is my example:
https://bpetty-formfast.github.io/PWA-v1

I tried using 192x192 by itself, then I added 512x512 without any luck.  What am I missing?

```
"icons": [{
    "src": "Logo-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
},{
    "src": "Splash-512x512.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
}],
```

**Update:**
Not a duplicate of: Can't get splash screen icon on Android Chrome PWA

See the accepted answer for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get splash screen icon on Android Chrome PWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800285/cant-get-splash-screen-icon-on-android-chrome-pwa)

Comment: @BruceM, this was not a duplicate.  Asked 3 months before the other question, this situation involved a case where I was not seeing a splash screen icon at all as opposed to the wrong one.  Your question did inspire me to see if this problem was actually due to a Chrome defect.  After updating Chrome to 71, from 69, everything now works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must have been a defect that was fixed in Chrome 71 for Android.  After doing a few updates, as I was using Chrome 69 before, I can now see the splash screen image as intended in my PWA.  I guess such is life when you are using a brand new technology that may not be quite ready for mainstream adoption.